# Biding object to ng-repeat select Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to finish CRUD on my project, but i have a problem.
When i tried to binding to modal `EmployeeDetail.DeptID` to select `Department` but it fail. Here is my code

HTML

```
<div ng-model="EmployeeDetail">
            <input type="text" ng-model="EmployeeDetail.EmpName" placeholder="Name" />
            <select id="Departments" ng-selected="//Some thing in here!">
                <option ng-repeat="dept in Departments" value="{{dept.DeptId}}">{{dept.DeptName}}</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" ng-model="EmployeeDetail.Address" placeholder="Address" />
            <input type="text" ng-model="EmployeeDetail.Email" placeholder="Mail" />

            <select>
                <option ng-selected="EmployeeDetail.Gender==true" value="true">Male</option>
                <option ng-selected="EmployeeDetail.Gender==false" value="false">Female</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" ng-model="EmployeeDetail.YearOfBirth" />
            <button value="create" ng-click="createEmployee()" ng-show="create">Submit</button>
            <button value="update" ng-click="updateEmployee()" ng-show="update">Update</button>
            <button value="cancel" ng-click="cancelEmployee()" ng-show="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
```

JS

```
var loadData = function () {
    $http.get(urlE).then(function (response) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(response.data);       
        $scope.Employees = obj;
        $('#empTable').DataTable();     
    });
    $http.get(urlD).then(function(response){
        var obj = JSON.parse(response.data);   
        $scope.Departments = obj;
    })
}

loadData();

$scope.edit = function (emp) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: urlE + "/" + emp.EmpID
    }).then(function (response) {
        var obj = response.data;
        $scope.EmployeeDetail = obj;
        console.log(obj);
        $scope.updateEmployee = function () {
            $http({ method: 'POST', url: "api/Employees/Update", data: obj }).then(function (response) {
                alert("Edit success!");
                loadData();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I'm binding a `Employee` to input correctly, but dropdown list `Departments` cannot. I want to binding `Employee.DeptId` to `select id="Departments"` and show to view `DepartmentsName` with id. I'm starting use AngularJS and something i dont understand. Can you expland for me and show me RIGHT way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your gender property a boolean with true for male and false for female? This seems like a strange design decision and I imagine could upset some people.

Comment: Sorry, im just try angularjs last day. And this gender i choose that way but think not correctly. Can you show me the right way! Thank you

Comment: How do we solve the gender issue? Not a question I want to tackle. Probably should be a free text box that allows people to enter their identified gender rather than true for male and false for female.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-model and options

```
<select id="Departments" ng-model="Employee.DeptId" ng-options="dept.DeptId as dept.DeptName for dept in Departments"></select>
```